# Explorer.exe crashes and screen blinks to tiles background color of tiles menu for 1 second

Tags: windows-8.1, crash

I recently installed windows and updated all drivers. But some minutes after login to windows screen starts to flashing between current program and background color of windows tiles.

I checked [this page in eightforums](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/57887-windows-explorer-crashing-flashes-screen.html) and windows files are now verified (and without corruption).

This is the error in Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54503a3a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17630, time stamp: 0x54b0e17a
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000000000081d68
Faulting process id: 0x92c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d07208efb9f714
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 2de5c179-ddfc-11e4-825b-f0bf97e4261a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What else can cause this problem?

**System information:**

- Sony VAIO VPCSE23FX
- Windows 8.1 X64
- Drive: SSD Samsung (newly added)

By signing out windows and loging in again, Windows explorer acts normally again.

Comment: IS this a newly assembled machine?  Does it behave the same way while booted in Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, it's vaio VPCSE23FX + New SSD Drive. Ok i'll check it in safe mode.

Comment: Can you do a system restore to a date/time before the updates were installed?

Comment: @BigChris Before driver updates? Drivers are same drivers that i used in previous windows 8.1 that was installed on same laptop. Just now i used another ISO file for windows (same 8.1 x64 but with new windows updates included) and a new SSD.

Comment: No problem in last 2 days. Just updated a vpn software (nextvpn).